# Vuetify - item-text item-value doesn't work at all

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to make use of `return-object` directive.

I have a list of objects:

```
[{"id":1,"profile_name":"Shoes store","quantity":55,"price_multiplier":0.5,"header":"This is a header","location":"New York","shipping_charge":5},{"id":2,"profile_name":"TV Store","quantity":8,"price_multiplier":1,"header":"This is a header. A little bit longer header than the header before so I can see how it behaves...","location":null,"shipping_charge":9}]
```

Both have `id` and `profile_name`.

I want to create a `v-select` that returns the selected object.

```
   <v-select v-model="template" :items="$store.state.listingTemplates"
                        :error-messages="formErrors.sku"
                        label="Template" outlined
                        hide-details
                        item-text="profile_name"
                        item-value="id"
                        return-object
        ></v-select>
```

It doesn't work - it uses `header` attribute as a `text` and I can't click/choose any of them.

Do you know where is the problem?

Comment: Which version of vuetify are you using? Is this the complete code? Because there is no reason for vuetify to use the header field as text by default. Usually if nothing is provided it should show just "Object object".

Comment: Just checked some versions of vuetify. Older versions don't have the item-text item-value props, so make sure you are using the current version of vuetify. (can confirm this "issue" in 0.14), but newer versions such as 2.* are working as expected.

Comment: Yes, this is the complete code. I even checked the store if it's in proper format. It is. I use theme and in package.json there is `"vuetify": "^2.4.3",`

Comment: I use Lux Theme

Comment: And which version is installed (package lock/yarn lock)? Is there also 2.*?

Comment: 2.4.8. `  "node_modules/vuetify": {
      "version": "2.4.8",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/vuetify/-/vuetify-2.4.8.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-rJYyzSO4Qsm/Q79W4FAUedgIDzUvx2uXzXXQ7OB2z9kAAkVOpTdMFY0CnpBcvlYbXOYy/mJ81/yUCV1ZAvJ3FQ=="
    },`

Comment: I guess the reason why it uses header is because it's the first property, if the object properties are sorted alphabetically. Your code works for me, must be something very silly that is missing. Have you tried any other components ? that might help narrow down if it's something related to v-select or if it's more general to your setup of vuetify

Answer (score 0):

The [docs for `v-select.items`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-select/#props-items) indicate that `header` is a special key that renders a non-selectable item:

> Objects that have a **header** or **divider** property are considered special cases and generate a list header or divider; these items are not selectable.

As a workaround, you could use a computed prop that extracts only the needed fields from `$store.state.listingTemplates` (i.e., `profile_name` and `id`):

```js
export default {
  computed: {
    computedListingTemplates() {
      return this.$store.state.listingTemplates.map(t => ({
        text: t.profile_name,
        value: t.id,
        item: t, // also return original object
      }))
    }
  }
}
```

Then use that computed prop with `v-select`, while removing the `item-text` and `item-value` props:

```html
<v-select :items="computedListingTemplates">
```

Note the computed prop mapping also returns the original object in an `item` property, and with `<v-select return-object>`, the `v-model` will include the original object.

*Example value of the `v-model` variable:*

```js
{
  "text": "TV Store",
  "value": 2,
  "item": {
    "id": 2,
    "profile_name": "TV Store",
    "quantity": 8,
    "price_multiplier": 1,
    "header": "This is a header. A little bit longer header than the header before so I can see how it behaves...",
    "location": null,
    "shipping_charge": 9
  }
}
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/xxgdQpE?editors=1010)

Comment: Thanks, yes I do that this way. I just wanted to spare some code because I need to get the object, not just it's id. So I use another method that finds for the object in listingTemplates by it's id.

Comment: You can include the original item in the computed prop's mapping. See updated answer and demo.

Answer (score 0):

**vuetify: ^3.5.2, Feb 2024.**

To date this is still broken, `v-list` is not working with `item-text` `item-value` properties, their API docs and/or codebase doesn't line up.

You have 2 choices:

**Easy one**, `yourItems` object structure must contain `{ title: 'blah' }` field. Do not use `item-text` `item-value` properties in `<v-list :items="yourItems" return-object>` and it picks up the title field and works automatically.

**Hard one**, implement your own template for the item and selection slots. It is more trouble as you need styling and extra custom sub-components if you have multiple=true and chips...etc. So I suggest you rather change the data structure to fit with method 1.

```
<v-list ...>
  <template v-slot:item="{item}">
    {{item.id}} {{item.profile_name}} //dropdown menu item
  </template>    
  <template v-slot:selection="{item}">
    {{item.id}} {{item.profile_name}} //input box selected item 
  </template>
</v-list>
```